# How to return rules on Exchange mailbox?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have code to retrieve rules that works on Outlook 2013. It does not work on a machine that runs Outlook 2016.

```vb
Set colRules = Session.DefaultStore.GetRules()
    
For Each oRule In colRules
    ruleName = oRule.Name
    If Left(ruleName, 21) = "AutoCategorize into *" Then
        oRule.Execute (True)
    End If
Next
```

The problem according to my debugging, is in the returned colRules object.

On 2016, it shows it has 26 items, but contains none:

Debug view image in 2016
[image]

On Outlook 2013, that same object shows all the 26 items (rules):
Debug view image in 2013
[image]

- The rules wizard does show all the 26 rules, on both machines;
- Some of the rules were defined on the computer running Outlook 2013, so they show as *(For other computer)* on the 2016 rules wizard;
- OutlookSpy Store-->Functions-->GetRules returns the same result: (Can't post image, not enough reputation.)

**I found the reason, but not the solution.**
The rules object contains rules 'from another computer'.

I deleted all the rules marked 'from another computer' to test.
Now it did find all the remaining rules. Same for OutlookSpy.
It cannot stay like this, since it is an Exchange mailbox, it removed the rules from the other computer as well.
I tested this on another account and got the same result.

Comment: Do you see the rules on the MAPI level in OutlookSpy (http://www.dimastr.com/outspy)? Go to the Inbox folder, click IMAPIFolder button, go to the PR_RULES_TABLE tab (if visible).

Comment: Dmitry, I am not familiar with OutlookSpy, but I did add it and followed your instructions, however in the window that pops there is no tab with that name.

Comment: I fiddled more with OutlookSpy. If I click "Store" then on the "Functions" tab I click "GetRules", I get a window that says there are 26 rules, but none of them show up. So basically it is the same. I will add that screenshot to the original message.

Comment: Is that an Exchange mailbox?

Comment: Yes it is an exchange mailbox. I read somewhere that if there is a broken rule then the object does not return any rules. This is not the case here as the rules work on another computer, but maybe this is something similar and it thinks a rule is broken because it belongs to another computer.

Comment: Hmmm.. So if you call GetRules in OutlookSpy, the Rules window that pops up shows Count property == 26, but IEnumVariant tab is empty?

Comment: Exactly @Dmitry !! 
I would have showed you a screenshot, but I cant load another image due to reputation

Comment: Is there more than one Exchange mailbox in the profile?

Comment: There is one exchange mailbox in this profile, but there are two profiles. This is the correct mailbox. 26 rules is what I e pact to find and it matches the rules wizard. It just does not show them. But since the wizard can see them, it must use a different way to get to them. Any ideas how?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the macro below which I created, after a struggle, to help me understand where my rules are held within my Outlook 2016 installation because they were not where I thought they were.

All but two of my stores generate the message: “440 This store does not support rules. Could not complete the operation.”  For all these stores the rules are in the default store “outlook data file”.  But one store contains its own rules.

With my Outlook installation, the store with its own rules has an extension of “OST” indicating it is an offline store.  “outlook data file” and all the other stores have an extension of “PST”.

I would like to know what this macro generates for you.  Are your rules in an OST store and not the default store as you expect?

```
Public Sub DemoRules()

  Dim ColRules As Outlook.Rules
  Dim ErrDesc As String
  Dim ErrNum As Long
  Dim InxStoreCrnt As Long
  Dim RuleCrnt As Outlook.Rule

  With Session
    For InxStoreCrnt = 1 To .Stores.Count
      With .Stores(InxStoreCrnt)
        Debug.Print .DisplayName
        Set ColRules = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ColRules = .GetRules()
        ErrNum = Err.Number
        ErrDesc = Err.Description
        On Error GoTo 0
        If ErrNum <> 0 Then
          Debug.Print "  " & ErrNum & " " & ErrDesc
        Else
          If Not ColRules Is Nothing Then
            If ColRules.Count = 0 Then
              Debug.Print "  no rules in this store"
            Else
              For Each RuleCrnt In ColRules
                Debug.Print "  " & RuleCrnt.Name
              Next
            End If
          Else
            Debug.Print " No error but GetRules returned Nothing"
          End If
        End If
      End With
      Set ColRules = Nothing
    Next
  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I used something similar to loop over the stores and get the rules of each one and it still did not work. I have 3 stores and one of them completely fails when I try to get the rules, the other has 0 rules and the first says it has 26 rules but there are no items.I at least owe you to try your code - so will post shortly results...

Comment: So I tried it and got a runtime error - it was expected: the code fails in the line: For Each RuleCrnt In ColRules. This because ColRules is empty but the count is 26.

Comment: Take a look at the image I provided from the debugger.It shows the structure of colRules . This is obviously a microsoft bug. The question is: is there another way to get it to display the rules?

Comment: I do not think I can help you. I have recently upgraded to Outlook 2016 and I keep finding items in unexpected places.  I was hoping that was the case with you since my rules were not where I expected.  Best of luck in finding a solution.